# Setting up custom post type archives in WP3.1? Any luck?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, customization

I've just moved a site I'm developing to WP3.1 so that I can take advantage of and start testing some of the new features. I'm especially liking the `has_archive` parameter in registering custom post types. I had a post type called 'recipes', and added this line to the args on registering it:

```
'has_archive' => 'recipe-listings',
```

From what I understand, that should generate the rewrite rules necessary to make **/recipe-listings/** be equivalent to **/?post_type=recipe**. However, I can't seem to get it working.

The generic form http://amritafood.com/?post_type=recipe works fine, but http://amritafood.com/recipe-listings/ just goes to 404. What else do I need to do to get custom post type archives working properly? Has anyone else worked it out yet?

Comment: Just to be clear: did you flush your rewrite rules already? Do links to individual posts work?

Comment: Yeah, I ran the flush_rewrite_rules once, and the links to individual posts work fine. The url ?post_type=recipe is pulling from my archive-recipe.php template, so the archive functionality seems to be working. Guess I'm just having a problem with generating the rewrite rules.

Comment: Doh... never mind. I was flushing rules at the wrong point. Flushing rules *after* the post types were registered did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the question too soon. And thanks to @Jan Fabry for pointing me in the right direction.

In case anyone else has this problem, here's the answer.

Any time the rewrite rules are changed (adding a new post type, changing the slug or the has_archive slug, etc.) you have to call `flush_rewrite_rules` once. It has to be called after the post types are registered. I put it at the very end of my function which registered the post types on 'init', visited the site once, then deleted it out. Now the site works fine.

Comment: You don't even need to do that, just visit the permalink settings page and hit save, it's harder to get this process wrong.. ;)

Comment: @t31os: Even quicker: don't hit save, the rules are flushed just by loading the permalink settings page.

Comment: I thought that were the case, but figured an extra click wouldn't hurt... :)